# Confusion about definition on surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

I'm taking a class on Analysis II and we're currently working on surfaces. The professor gave us a definition that states

> Let $1\leqslant m < n$. The set $S \subset \Bbb R^n$ is an $m$-dimensional surface if $S$ is homeomorphic with the open set $U \subset \Bbb R^m.$

I cannot find this definition anywhere else nor some example problems.

I found one problem on some old lecture note which states that

> Let $S= \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid x^2 +y^2+z^2 =1, z >0 \}.$ Determine if $S$  is a $2$-dimensional surface in $\Bbb R^3$.

So in this particular case I would have to find the parametrization for this and see if it's homeomorphic?

If anyone could help me find some material that has a similar definition that would probably clear this up a bit.

Comment: I'm sure that's not what the definition says. Did you copy it exactly word for word?

Comment: I did. She wrote it on the fly on a lecture to a chalkboard so there may be some mistakes. Might you happen to know the actual one?